# watch doesn't refresh the page on file change (express site)

Tags: node.js, express, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

It would be nice to have the browser automatically reload the page when I change a project file. I have this node-express site with the server being defined in 'server.js'

However, I've tried different grunt configurations, but none of them caused the browser to reload on a file change although the 'watch' task prints a message that the file changed!

Here is the relevant grunt configuration:

```
watch: {
    all: {
        files: 'views/index.ejs', // for now only watch this file!
        options: {
            livereload: true
        }
    }
},
express: {
    options: {
        background: true,
        error: function(err, result, code) {},
        fallback: function() {},
        port: 3000
        delay: 0,
        output: ".+",
        debug: false
    },
    dev: {
        options: {
            script: './server.js',
            node_env: 'development',
            livereload: true
        }
    }
}
....

grunt.registerTask('server', [
    'express:dev',
    'open',
    'watch'
])
};
```

And to run the task I do

```
$> grunt server
```

Can someone explain what is wrong with this configuration ?

thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the livereload browser plugin from http://livereload.com/

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to use grunt livereload to reload css changes on my node.js pages. I am getting closer to solve my problem which is similar to yours. So from what i know so far and please correct me if i'm wrong you dont need to install "livereload browser plugin" right? I used grunt alone without node.js and i could just use livereload without installing "livereload browser plugin" i just had to add a line in my .html (the problem i run into with node is how to reload .ejs and i found this page/question on the way solving it) :   so i dont know if installing the livereload thing is another way to do the script part or if this is the case like i mentioned in my problem if i want to live reload .ejs i have to install the plugin.